# How to use tap gesture to offset an image or shape view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use SwiftUI to make it so that if I tap a circle, or image, or something of the sort, it will be offset to a certain location, and if I tap again, it will go back to the location, and toggle back and forwards likewise. I found a tutorial that taught me how to toggle a background color. https://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/swiftui-gesture-tutorial. If you didn't bother to read it, essentially the code is like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    // 1.
    @State private var didTap: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        // 2.
        Text("Tap me")
            .frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
            // 3.
            .gesture(TapGesture()
                .onEnded {
                    self.didTap.toggle()
                }
            )
            // 4.
            .background(didTap ? Color.blue : Color.red)
    }
}
```

I changed the

```
Text("Tap me")
    .frame(minWidth:0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
```

to

```
Circle()
    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
```

I was wondering if there was a way to make it so instead of the `.background(didTap ? Color.blue : Color.red)` I could incorporate the TapGesture boolean variable into a `.offset(x: __, y: __)`
somehow.

Comment: Do you want your circle to animate between the two positions? OR do you want it to add an offset on tap and on the second tap move it to original location?

Comment: The second, add an offset on tap and move to original location on another tap, and back and forwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is the solution you are looking for, also I have changed the way you are adding tap gesture.

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State private var didTap: Bool = false

    private var xOffset: CGFloat {
        return didTap ? 10.0 : 0.0
    }

    var body: some View {
        // 2.
        Circle()
            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
            .onTapGesture {
                self.didTap.toggle()
        }
            //The x-offset depends on didTap State
            .offset(x: xOffset, y: 0.0)
    }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, this is what I was looking for!